# Create function to calculate rcorr on subsets of data frame

Tags: r, hmisc

I currently manually create a correlation matrix of a large data.frame using the Hmisc Package as below:

```
mydatacorrelation001 <- rcorr(as.matrix(mydata, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"))
```

I now need to calculate the correlation between each variable over subsets based on calendar month periods (eg. '2015-05' or 'May-15').

The dates are currently 'daily' (eg. 2015-05-29) so I considered including a new column 'Month' as below:

```
mydata$Month <- factor(format(mydata$Date, "%B"),levels = month.name)
```

-Kindly suggested by @Andy Clifton in another answer

(although I would need this to be formatted as 'Mar-15' rather than 'March')

Is there next a way to automatically create each new rcorr matrix variable (Eg.mydatacorrelation002, mydatacorrelation003, and so on) for each month subset?

Thank you very much

Comment: Post the results of `dput(head(mydata))` if your data is not sensitive (after your Month transformation)

Comment: I cant get the Month transformation to work. It currently shows as; May or June etc. but I would need May-15 or Jun-15 as this data spans multiple years. Any ideas on that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example with fake data that will hopefully show you how to proceed with your data:

```
library(lubridate)
library(Hmisc)

## Create fake data
dates = seq(1.3e9, 1.3e9 + 100e6, length.out=1000)
class(dates) = "POSIXct"
set.seed(20)
dat = data.frame(dates, x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000))

# Add month-year column
dat$my = paste(month(dat$dates, label=TRUE), year(dat$dates), sep="-")

## Calculate correlations by month
corr.list = list()
corr.list = sapply(unique(dat$my), function(i) {
  corr.list[i] = rcorr(dat$x[dat$my==i], dat$y[dat$my==i])
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

The output is a list, where the correlation for each month-year is a separate list element. Here are the first and last elements of the output:

```
$`Mar-2011`
      x     y
x  1.00 -0.07
y -0.07  1.00

n= 17 


P
       x      y     
x        0.7831
y 0.7831       

...

$`May-2014`
      x     y
x  1.00 -0.64
y -0.64  1.00

n= 11 


P
       x      y     
x        0.0327
y 0.0327
```

**UPDATE:** Per your comment, you can just feed `rcorr` the whole subset of the data frame, minus the two date columns, as follows:

```
corr.list = list()
corr.list = sapply(unique(dat$my), function(i) {
  dat1 = dat[dat$my==i,]
  corr.list[i] = rcorr(as.matrix(dat1[, -grep("dates|my", names(dat1))]))
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

**UPDATE 2:** To answer your follow-up question about outputting to a csv file. Here's one way to do that:

```
# Write correlation matrices to a csv file
lapply(names(corr.list), function(my) {
  cat(my, file="corr.csv", append=TRUE)
  cat("\n", file="corr.csv", append=TRUE)
  write.table(corr.list[[my]][1], "corr.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
  cat("\n", file="corr.csv", append=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this creates the month-year column perfectly. The only problem is that I have multiple variables (not just x and y). I would like to output a list for which I do not need to explicitly name the columns. eg. rcorr(as.matrix(dat, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")).

Comment: That's great, it creates the correlation matrix exactly as I need, can I please ask one final question.. I usually assign the output of the rcorr as a variable eg. 'cordata' then convert the matrix to a DF using the following code `df.cordata.r=data.frame(cordata$r)` then write to CSV using `write.csv(df.cordata.r,'cordata.csv')`. This doesn't seem to work after using the function. How could I write this to CSV? Thanks again